Horizontal scroll in calendar with panResponder not working properly
I'm creating a calendar in react native. I have the arrows to move to next and previous month that works correctly and I'm trying to use an horizontal scroll or drag to move between months but no matter on which month the view is, when I scroll to the previous month it makes the animation, but renders the month previous to the actual date. and same happens with the next month scroll.
Also I can't make the calendar view grow the full space to adjust if I put it in a Component in an app later.
This is the full code:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Dimensions, 
  TouchableOpacity, 
  FlatList, 
  Animated, 
  PanResponder
} from 'react-native';

let screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width
let screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height
let lenguage = "es"

export default function Calendar() {
  const [currentDay, setCurrentDay] = useState(new Date());
  const [monthdays, setMonthDays] = useState([])
  const position = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current

  let currentDate = new Date()
  let actualyear = new Date().getFullYear()
  
  //arreglo weekDays con los dias de la semana de lunes a domingo, idioma ajustable
  const weekdaysArray = [...Array(7).keys()]
  const intlWeekDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lenguage, {weekday: "short"})
  const weekDays = weekdaysArray.map(weekDayIndex => {
    const weekDayName = intlWeekDay.format(new Date(2021, 10, weekDayIndex +1))
    return weekDayName
  })

  //arreglo months con los meses, idioma ajustable
  const monthsArray = [...Array(12).keys()]
  const intlMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lenguage, {month: "short"})
  const months = monthsArray.map(monthIndex => {
    const month = intlMonth.format(new Date(actualyear, monthIndex))
    return month
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const today = new Date();
    setCurrentDay(today);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const daysInMonth = new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
    const emptyCellsBefore = firstDayOfMonth === 0 ? 6 : firstDayOfMonth - 1;
    const isCurrentMonth = (currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth()) === (currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth());
    
    const days = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= emptyCellsBefore; i++) {
      days.push({ 
        key: `-${i}`, 
        day: new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth(), 0 - (emptyCellsBefore - i)).getDate(), 
        isCurrentDay: false,
        shadowed: true
      });
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      const isCurrentDay = i === currentDate.getDate() && isCurrentMonth;
      days.push({
        key: i.toString(),
        day: i,
        isCurrentDay
      });
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= (42 - emptyCellsBefore - daysInMonth); i++) {
      days.push({ 
        key: (daysInMonth + i).toString(), 
        day: new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth(), daysInMonth + i).getDate(), 
        isCurrentDay: false,
        shadowed: true
      });
    }
    console.log(currentDay)
    setMonthDays(days);
  }, [currentDay])

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    const {day, key, isCurrentDay, shadowed} = item

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={key}
        style={shadowed ? styles.dayContainerEmpty : styles.dayContainer}
        onPress={() => handleDayPress(day)}
      >
        <Text style={shadowed ? styles.emptyDayText : [styles.dayText, isCurrentDay && styles.selectedDayText]}>{day}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  const handleDayPress = (day) => {
    
  };

  const prevMonth = () => {
    const newDatePrev = new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth() - 1);
    setCurrentDay(newDatePrev)

    Animated.timing(position, {
      toValue: screenWidth,
      duration: 100,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start(() => {
      position.setValue(-screenWidth)
      Animated.timing(position, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }).start()
    })
  };

  const nextMonth = () => {
    const newDateNext = new Date(currentDay.getFullYear(), currentDay.getMonth() + 1);
    setCurrentDay(newDateNext)

    Animated.timing(position, {
      toValue: -screenWidth,
      duration: 100,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start(() => {
      position.setValue(screenWidth),
      Animated.timing(position, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }).start()
    })
  };

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue(gestureState.dx)
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if(gestureState.dx > 150) {
          prevMonth();
        } else if(gestureState.dx < -150) {
          nextMonth();
        } else {
          position.setValue(0)
        }
      }
    })
  ).current

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.arrows}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={prevMonth}>
            <Text style={styles.arrow}>{'<-'}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <Text style={styles.monthText}>{currentDay.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', { month: 'long' })}</Text>
          
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={nextMonth}>
            <Text style={styles.arrow}>{'->'}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.weekDays}>
        {weekDays.map(day => 
          <View key={day} style={styles.textDayContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.textDayContainerText}>{day}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>

      <Animated.View 
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        style={[
          styles.daysContainer,
          {transform:[{translateX: position}]},
        ]}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <FlatList
          scrollEnabled={false}
          data={monthdays}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          numColumns={7}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 30
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  monthText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  arrows: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingHorizontal: 30
  },
  arrow: {
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  textDayContainer: {
    width: (screenWidth - 40) / 7,
    alignItems: "center"
  },  
  textDayContainerText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  weekDays: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 10
  },
  daysContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 5
  },
  dayContainer: {
    height: 100,
    width: (screenWidth - 40)/7,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    paddingTop: 1,
    paddingRight: 3
  },
  dayContainerEmpty: {
    width: (screenWidth - 40)/7,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#e1e1e1",
    borderColor: "grey",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    paddingTop: 1,
    paddingRight: 3
  },
  dayText: {
    fontSize: 10
  },
  emptyDayText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: "grey"
  },
  selectedDayText: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

Expect to scroll to next and previous month and go to the previous or next of the month in the view
